# C# Join Strings of two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, join

I have two `string array`s

```
array1 = { "test", "test", "test" }
array2 = { "completed", "completed", "completed" }
```

And I want to join the strings in the two arrays (they are always the same size) -> so I want to have one array which contains

```
array = { "test completed", "test completed", "test completed" }
```

Everything I found was only joining the arrays so I have a 6 items in array. Is it possible to do this without looping through the whole array (i.e. with `LINQ` or something like that) ?

Comment: Anyway note that linq also loops through whole array.(not always but in this case Zip in given answers) Thats just what you dont see behind the scenes!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You got to be kidding. LINQ is a magic, it never does `for`, `foreach` and any other kind of obsolete loops :-)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yep, you're right, but i wanted a clean code :) thats awesome with LINQ :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with [Enumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method like this:

`var joined = array1.Zip(array2, (first, second) => first + " " + second);`

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with LINQ using `Zip`:

```
var res = array1.Zip(array2, (a, b) => $"{a} {b}").ToArray();
```

**Note:** If you do not have the latest compiler, use `a+" "+b` instead of `$"{a} {b}"`.